# mongo how to query nested json

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, projection, bson

How to query to retrieve the value of id from below json structure.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53b144a83e1e1c5728677bb8"),
  "classes": 
    {
       "class" : [{"id":"1234","name":"A"},{"id":"4321","name":"B"}]
    }
}
```

From above json, I want the `id` values to be export into csv.

Sample Output of CSV :

```
id,name     
1234,"A"
4321,"B"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#projection) along with [dot-notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) (for accessing the inner document):

```
coll.find({ <your filter> }, { _id: 0, "classes.class": 1 }
```